# Excel VBA using Range with variables

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to clear a range of cells with the use of a variable. For some background I have values in A-G that will be updated regularly while the values in I-K need to remain constant.

I am trying to use the value stored in myCell (in this example A8) to guide my clear command to be everything from it to G100

```
Range(myCell, "G100").ClearContents
```

I have tried several variations of this but it never seems to take so there must be something I am missing.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.

```
Range(myCell, range("G100")).ClearContents
```